# Creating an XML file from an IList

Tags: c#, ilist

I have an IList to work with.

Can I loop through the rows in the list and create an XML file from this? If so how would I go about doing it?

I have been trying to get to grips with XDocument but I fail to see how I can loop through the IList using this method.

Comment: You can create a string, and save list values to variables in string and call Load function to loop through the nodes

Comment: You're going to need to be more clear.  What do you have a list of?  What does your XML need to look like?

Comment: Can you show your list container here? And, of course, your XDocument code structure?

Comment: It is just a list of emails gathered from an SQL sproc

Comment: You should consider using the [XML serialiser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Look into [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2baksw0z%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) ... if you don't need low level control on the Xml structure that will be created there's no need to loop yourself.

Comment: I've deleted my comment because I went the `string` way, which does not involve `XDocument` and thus is out of scope. Mind that you cannot directly serialize a list of interface with `XMLSerializer`, so you'll have to transform the items manually. This means you have to *materialize* the items in a second list such as: from `List<IMyInterface>` to an `IList<string>` or similar before you feed it into the serializer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), add `System.Xml.Serialization` to you project's References and:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Program {
    static void Main() {
        List<string> Data=new List<string> { "A","B","C","D","E" };

        XmlSerializer XMLs=new XmlSerializer(Data.GetType());
        XMLs.Serialize(Console.Out,Data);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

I used `Console.Out` to give you a quick one-liney example, but you can pick any `Stream`, most likely a file to write to.

Answer (score 1):

In two lines:

```
IList<string> list  = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"};
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Root", list.Select(x => new XElement("Child", x))));
```

do not forget usings:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

If the original `IList` is a non-generic `IList`, you will need to include a call to `Enumerable.Cast<T>()` so that the `Select()` can work. E.g.:

```
IList list  = new List<string> {"A", "B", "C"};
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Root",
    list.Cast<string>().Select(x => new XElement("Child", x))));
```

Comment: My list is an IList and an IList doesn't like .Select - could you advise?

Comment: I am using all of that, still having the same issues

Comment: @MatthewHarris What if you called .ToList() or .ToArray() on your IList first? This might impact performance if the list is large AND also will break the "lazy chain" that LINQ queries provides (= the list will become evaluated at this moment instead of only using needed elements at the very last moment). But it depends if you need it to be lazy at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after a fairly simple structure from a list of strings then this will work:

```
var list = new List<string> { "Joe", "Jim", "John" };

var document = new XDocument();
var root = new XElement("Root");
document.Add(root);
list.ForEach(x => root.Add(new XElement("Name", x)));
```

Comment: My list is an IList and an IList doesn't like .ForEach - could you advise?

Comment: Use .Select as with the solution @Alex Joukovsky has provided.

Comment: Same issue - IList does not contain definition for select , thank you for the help!